# How do I export existing azure application registration as terraform code?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-app-registration

I have two azure application registrations which are used for authentication & authorization. I would like to know how I can export them into terraform code with keeping their settings and configurations. I have been checking [Azure/Aztfexport](https://github.com/Azure/aztfexport) however I could not export my existing app registrations. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

This is one of the app registrations that I have for demo purpose:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have been checking Azure/Aztfexport however I could not export my existing app registrations. Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Yes, you can export an existing **Azure AD Application** to **terraform.tfstate** using the below **Terraform** code.

Here is the **Terraform** code to export the **Azure AD Application**.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azuread_application" "existingADapplicationname" {
}
output "azuread_application" {
  value = azuread_application.existingADapplicationname
}
```

**Terraform Result.**

[image]

**terraform.tfstate**

[image]

Reference: [azuread_application](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application)

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. I was asking how to export my app registrations as terraform code, not exporting them into a terraform state

Comment: Where you want to export the Azure AD Application? The terraform import azuread_application.aksapp xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx will import the application to Terraform state.

Comment: I want to export the application registration into TERRAFORM CODE DEFINITION, not the STATE. Like after exporting, I will have something like `resource "azuread_application" "myapplication" { ....... } `

Comment: You want to use the existing Azure AD Application, you can use data "azuread_application" block. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/application

Comment: I honestly am not sure whether or not you understood the question. Please take a look at what `aztfexport` does. Your last comment is  not relevant.

Comment: I already know what to use, I just want a tool (in this case `aztfexport`) to create the terraform code without me explicitly re-writing all the configurations of application registration into terraform code.

Answer (score 0):

As per answer from `aztfexport` developers that you can find [here](https://github.com/Azure/aztfexport/issues/395#issuecomment-1533986065):

> The `azuread_application` belongs to the `azuread` provider, while `aztfexport` currently only support `azurerm` resources and they didn't plan to support `azuread` at this moment as it is not ARM based, but uses MS Graph API.

Which means it is currently not possible to export an `azuread` application registration as terraform code